# Conditional lead/lag function PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
Name   activity  time

user1  A1        12:00
user1  E3        12:01
user1  A2        12:02
user2  A1        10:05
user2  A2        10:06
user2  A3        10:07
user2  M6        10:07
user2  B1        10:08
user3  A1        14:15
user3  B2        14:20
user3  D1        14:25
user3  D2        14:30
```

Now, I need a result like this:

```
Name   activity  next_activity

user1  A2        NULL
user2  A3        B1
user3  A1        B2
```

I would like to check for every user the last activity from group A and what type of activity took place next from group B (activity from group B always takes place after activity from group A). Other types of activity are not interesting for me. I've tried to use the `lead()` function, but it hasn't worked.

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: `activity from group B always takes place after activity from group A`. That means, there are never two consecutive "B" activities per user? Also: your sample data suggests that all activities per user always happen in sequence, i.e. A1 -> A2 -> A3, .. never A3 -> A2. Correct? And: Postgres version?

Comment: yes :) you're right :)

Answer (score 11):

Your definition:

> activity from group B always takes place after activity from group A.

.. logically implies that there is, per user, 0 or 1 B activity after 1 or more A activities. Never more than 1 B activities in sequence.

You can make it work with a single window function, `DISTINCT ON` and `CASE`, which should be the fastest way for *few* rows per user (also see below):

```
SELECT name
     , CASE WHEN a2 LIKE 'B%' THEN a1 ELSE a2 END AS activity
     , CASE WHEN a2 LIKE 'B%' THEN a2 END AS next_activity
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
          name
        , lead(activity) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time DESC) AS a1
        , activity AS a2
   FROM   t
   WHERE (activity LIKE 'A%' OR activity LIKE 'B%')
   ORDER  BY name, time DESC
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=77f7ad7e929b8a1d6148e4e937d54edb)*

An SQL `CASE` expression defaults to `NULL` if no `ELSE` branch is added, so I kept that short.

Assuming `time` is defined `NOT NULL`. Else, you might want to add `NULLS LAST`. Why?

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

`(activity LIKE 'A%' OR activity LIKE 'B%')` is more verbose than `activity ~ '^[AB]'`, but typically faster in older versions of Postgres. About pattern matching:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

#### Conditional window functions?

That's actually *possible*. You can combine the aggregate `FILTER` clause with the `OVER` clause of window functions. **However**:

1. The `FILTER` clause itself can only work with values from the current row.
2. More importantly, `FILTER` is not implemented for pure genuine functions like `lead()` or `lag()` (up to Postgres 13) - only for [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

If you try:

```
lead(activity) FILTER (WHERE activity LIKE 'A%') OVER () AS activity
```

Postgres will tell you:

> ```
> FILTER is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions
> ```

About `FILTER`:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)
- [Referencing current row in FILTER clause of window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function/31397894#31397894)

#### Performance

For ***few*** users with ***few*** rows per user, pretty much *any* query is fast, even without index.

For ***many*** users and ***few*** rows per user, the first query above should be fastest. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For ***many*** rows per user, there are (potentially *much*) faster  techniques, depending on details of your setup. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Answer (score 0):

```
select      distinct on(name) name,activity,next_activity

from       (select name,activity,time
                  ,lead(activity) over (partition by name order by time) as next_activity

            from   t

            where  left(activity,1) in ('A','B')
            ) t

where       left(activity,1) = 'A'

order by    name,time desc
```