# Get pairs of rows less than an hour apart

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table like this in a PostgreSQL database:

```
name, salary, birthdate, last_update
1, Ann Alden, 123000.00, 1986-03-04, 2022-01-04 11:30:30.0
3, Chloe Cat, 99999999.99, 1999-01-15, 2022-01-04 12:25:45.0
4, Don Denton, 91234.24, 2004-08-03, 2022-01-04 12:45:00.0
5, Eddy Edwards, 55125125.25, 2003-05-17, 2022-01-05 23:00:00.0
```

How would I return all fields of a pair of people where the `last_update` field is less than an hour apart?

I would expect the output of:

```
id, name, salary, birthdate, last_update, id, name, salary, birthdate, last_update
1, Ann Alden, 123000.00, 1986-03-04, 2022-01-04 11:30:30.0, 3, Chloe Cat, 99999999.99, 1999-01-15, 2022-01-04 12:25:45.0
3, Chloe Cat, 99999999.99, 1999-01-15, 2022-01-04 12:25:45.0, 4, Don Denton, 91234.24, 2004-08-03, 2022-01-04 12:45:00.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

For only **consecutive pairs**, use one of the [window functions **`lead()`** or **`lag()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```sql
SELECT (t1).*, (t2).*
FROM  (
   SELECT t AS t1, lead(t) OVER (ORDER BY last_update, id) AS t2
   FROM   tbl AS t
   ) sub
WHERE  (t1).last_update > (t2).last_update - interval '1 hour';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1b971cfb0e39fed2a442009657878299)*

The query only considers *consecutive* rows (according to `last_update`). Else it actually gets simpler but more expensive, and you get *many* pairs for clusters of updates. (See below.)

Also, while `last_update` is not defined `UNIQUE`, there is ambiguity in the sort order. I use id as tiebreaker. (You did not specify.)

Since you ask for whole rows, I use [row types (composite values)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) to keep it simple. All parentheses are required.

The result has **duplicate column names** like you requested. That's allowed in Postgres, but I wouldn't do it as it introduces ambiguity that many clients can't handle.

Related:

- [Conditional lead/lag function PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796929/conditional-lead-lag-function-postgresql/41797399#41797399)

To get **all pairs**, not just consecutive ones:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 ON t1.last_update < t2.last_update
             AND t1.last_update > t2.last_update - interval '1 hour';
```