# Updating previous row using sql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table name p_Details with (id,eff_dt,amt,change,month). For each ID and change combination there are 12 records for 12 months. Data looks like below.

| id | eff_dt | amt | change | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 2 |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 3 |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 4 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 100 | 1-Mar | Null | 2 | 1 |
| 100 | 1-Mar | Null | 2 | 2 |
| 100 | 1-Mar | 400 | 2 | 3 |
| 100 | 1-Mar | 400 | 2 | 4 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 100 | 1-Apr | Null | 3 | 1 |
| 100 | 1-Apr | Null | 3 | 2 |
| 100 | 1-Apr | Null | 3 | 3 |
| 100 | 1-Apr | 500 | 3 | 4 |

If any combination of Id and change is having Null value for a particular month, then amt from same id and same month but from previous change number will be copy over to the present row.
Final table should look like below after update.

| id | eff_dt | amt | change | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 2 |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 3 |
| 100 | 1-Jan | 300 | 1 | 4 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 100 | 1-Mar | 300 | 2 | 1 |
| 100 | 1-Mar | 300 | 2 | 2 |
| 100 | 1-Mar | 400 | 2 | 3 |
| 100 | 1-Mar | 400 | 2 | 4 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 100 | 1-Apr | 300 | 3 | 1 |
| 100 | 1-Apr | 300 | 3 | 2 |
| 100 | 1-Apr | 400 | 3 | 3 |
| 100 | 1-Apr | 500 | 3 | 4 |

Same Id and month combination can have N number of change numbers. I are trying to use `lag()` function  but it is not working.

Below is my query which is not giving desired result.

```
select
  case when amt is null then amt_new else amt end as amt,
  id,
  eff_dt,
  change,
  month
from (
  select
    id,
    eff_dt,
    change,
    month,
    amt,
    LAG(amt) OVER(partition id,month order by change) as amt_new
  from p_Details
) e
```

Comment: "*I are trying to use lag() function but it is not working.*" - please [edit] your question to show us the query you've tried

Comment: @Bergi I have added the query

Comment: What exactly is not working with that query?

Comment: To get the *last non-null* value in the window, you might want to use `LAG (amt) FILTER (WHERE amt IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY id, month ORDER BY change)` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796929/conditional-lead-lag-function-postgresql

Comment: @Bergi, in PostgreSQL (at least through 15.2), `FILTER` is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions such as `lead` and `lag`.

Comment: @JohnH Ah, I misunderstood Erwin's answer to the question I linked, as if it was implemented in Postgres 13. But your answer here has a nice workaround :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuitive approach to addressing the specified requirement is to use `LAG` to get the most recent non-NULL value. Unfortunately, that approach depends on features that aren't supported in PostgreSQL. One might next consider using `FIRST_VALUE` or `LAST_VALUE`, but the same limitations apply. Subqueries are an option, but the resulting code can seem complex and might perform poorly. Let's try a different approach.

`FILTER` is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions such as `LEAD` and `LAG`; however, it is available for aggregate window functions such as `ARRAY_AGG`. For data sets where the windowed partitions are large, this approach might be impractical. For the use case the OP presented, the partitions are sufficiently small for the following query to work efficiently:

```
WITH p_details (
  id,
  eff_dt,
  amt,
  change,
  month
) AS (
  VALUES (100, '1-Jan', 300, 1, 1),
    (100, '1-Jan', 300, 1, 2),
    (100, '1-Jan', 300, 1, 3),
    (100, '1-Jan', 300, 1, 4),
    (100, '1-Mar', NULL, 2, 1),
    (100, '1-Mar', NULL, 2, 2),
    (100, '1-Mar', 400, 2, 3),
    (100, '1-Mar', 400, 2, 4),
    (100, '1-Apr', NULL, 3, 1),
    (100, '1-Apr', NULL, 3, 2),
    (100, '1-Apr', NULL, 3, 3),
    (100, '1-Apr', 500, 3, 4))
SELECT
  id,
  eff_dt,
  COALESCE(amt, (ARRAY_AGG(amt) FILTER (WHERE amt IS NOT NULL)
                                OVER (PARTITION BY id, month ORDER BY change DESC
                                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1]) AS amt,
  change,
  month
FROM
  p_details
ORDER BY
  id,
  change,
  month;
```

This query finds the substitution value by taking the first element of an array consisting of prior non-NULL values sorted in descending change order. Because the values are sorted in descending change order, the concepts of past and present are inverted; therefore, the window definition references `FOLLOWING` instead of `PRECEDING` to access prior changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnH, it really works for me. If you could explain the query in more details it will be really helpful.

Comment: Play around with the query to investigate how it works. A good place to start would be to add `(ARRAY_AGG(amt) FILTER (WHERE amt IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY id, month ORDER BY change DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) AS past_changes` to the select list and then vary the filter, ordering, and window options to see their effects. That kind of experimentation will teach you much more than additional exposition on the workings for this particular case.