# Window functions filter through current row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-performance

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000013/optimize-slow-aggregates-in-lateral-join) question, where my query was improved to use window functions instead of aggregates inside a `LATERAL` join. While the query is now much faster, I've found that the results are not correct.

I need to perform computations on x year trailing time frames. For example, `price_to_maximum_earnings` is computed per row by getting `max(earnings)` over ten years ago to the current row, and dividing `price` by the result. We'll use 1 year for simplicity here.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/648ff/11) for this question. (Postgres 9.6)

As a simple example, `price` and `peak_earnings` for `2010-01-01` could be computed separately like this:

```
SELECT price
FROM security_data
WHERE date = '2010-01-01'
AND security_id = 'SPX';

SELECT max(earnings) AS min_earnings
FROM bloomberg.security_data
WHERE date >= '2000-01-01'
AND date <= '2010-01-01'
AND security_id = 'SPX';
```

To do this *per row*, I use the following:

```
SELECT security_id, date, price
     , CASE WHEN date1 >= min_date
            THEN price / NULLIF(max(earnings) FILTER (WHERE date >= date1) OVER w, 0) END AS price_to_peak_earnings
FROM
(
  SELECT record_id, security_id, price, date, earnings
           , (date - interval '1 y')::date AS date1
           , min(date) OVER (PARTITION BY security_id) AS min_date
      FROM   security_data
) d
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY security_id);
```

I believe the issue here stems from the use of `FILTER`, as it doesn't seem to be working as I want it to. Note that in the linked SQL Fiddle, I've displayed the result of the `FILTER`, and for each row the `peak_earnings` and `minimum_earnings` are just the max and min for the entire data set. They *should* be the max/min values of `earnings` from 1 year ago to the current row.

What's going on here? I know from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function) question that I can't simply say `FILTER (WHERE date >= date1 AND date <= current_row.date)`, so is there a solution I'm missing? I cannot use window frames because I have an uncertain number of rows for any given time frame, so I couldn't just say `OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. Can I use a frame *and* a filter? That might get over a year previous, then the filter could catch every invalid date. I've tried this but have not been successful.

Comment: Is it always a calendar year?  Or can you have, for example, a data point on 1st November, and need data for the 10 months "this" year and 2 months of the preceding year?

Comment: The SQL Fiddle has only calendar years but in practice there will be data for most days throughout the year. Your mentioned case would certainly come up.

Comment: But never more than one row per `(security_id, date)`, right?

Comment: Correct. There will never be duplicate rows per any `(security_id, date)` pair.

Comment: The closest I can get is left join on to a calendar and then hard code a year as 365 rows...   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c0f21/5  *(Other than a Triangle join...)*

Comment: That actually seems reasonable... not terribly elegant but for now I just need it to work.

Comment: @MatBailie: I agree. Either that, or we are back to `LATERAL` subqueries. @OP: are 365 x n good enough? (Error accumulates over 10 years.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yeah, that should be good for now. I'll only be doing yearly periods for now.

Comment: Another option, that deals with years accurately, but is likely to be slower than the alternative discussed above.  *(Though possibly faster than the initial LATERAL based option...)*  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5299/23

Comment: A slightly more "normal" version...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5299/29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use a frame and a filter?

You *can*. But either has restrictions:

- The expression in the `FILTER` clause only sees the respective row where it fetches values. There is no way to reference the row for which your window function computes values. So I don't see a way to formulate a filter depending on *that* row unless we make a *huge, expensive* cross join - the same row is used for many different computations. Or we are back to `LATERAL` subqueries that *can* reference the parent row.
- The frame definition on the other hand does not allow variables at all. It demands a fixed number, as discussed in the related answer you referenced:

  - [Referencing current row in FILTER clause of window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function)

These restrictions make your particular query hard to implement. This should be *correct* now:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT record_id, security_id, date, price
        , CASE WHEN do_calc THEN                max(earnings) OVER w1     END AS peak_earnings
        , CASE WHEN do_calc THEN                min(earnings) OVER w1     END AS minimum_earnings
        , CASE WHEN do_calc THEN price / NULLIF(max(earnings) OVER w1, 0) END AS price_to_peak_earnings
        , CASE WHEN do_calc THEN price / NULLIF(min(earnings) OVER w1, 0) END AS price_to_minimum_earnings
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, (date - 365) >= min_date AND s.record_id IS NOT NULL AS do_calc
      FROM  (
         SELECT security_id, min_date
              , generate_series(min_date, max_date, interval '1 day')::date AS date
         FROM  (
            SELECT security_id, min(date) AS min_date, max(date) AS max_date
            FROM   security_data
            GROUP  BY 1
            ) minmax
         ) d
      LEFT   JOIN  security_data s USING (security_id, date)
      ) sub1
   WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY security_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
   ) sub2
WHERE  record_id IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0fd2/2)

#### Notes

- Nothing in the question says that every `security_id` would have rows for the same days. Calculating min / max date per `security_id` in subquery `minmax` give us the minimum time frame.
- The time frame for calculations is exactly 365 day preceding the current date of the row and *not* including the current row (`ROWS BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`). It's typically more useful to *exclude* the current row from aggregations to be compared with the current row.
  I adapted the condition for calculations to the same time frame to avoid corner case oddities: `(date - 365) >= min_date`
- In the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b0fd2/2), where you added 1 row for every 1st of Jan, you can see the effect of leapyears contrasting with a fixed number of 365 day. The window frame is empty after leapyears (2001, 2005, ...).
- I am using all subqueries, which is typically a bit faster than CTEs.
- To be sure, we need to include `ORDER BY` in the frame definition. I updated my old answer you linked to accordingly:

  - [Referencing current row in FILTER clause of window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function)
- I use `w1` as window *name*, for the "1 year" period. You might add `w2`, etc. and can have any number of days for each. You could adapt to leapyears after all if you should need to. Might even generate the whole query depending on the current date ...

Comment: Your profile description is certainly true - thank you so much. This is uglier than I could have ever hoped for, but it works. I've checked it against previously computed values that are known to be correct.

Comment: @ztaylor54: Also consider the added explanation.

Comment: Your answer is comprehensive and the explanation makes sense. I am still learning, and you have aided me in that process. I am going to stick with this method as small inconsistencies around leapyears and such aren't a big enough issue (for my purposes) to properly resolve.