# PySpark Multiple Columns Using Windows

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Dataframe as follows:

```
|id |date_1    |date_2     |
+---+----------+-----------+
|0  |2017-01-21|2017-04-01 |
|1  |2017-01-22|2017-04-24 |
|2  |2017-02-23|2017-04-30 |
|3  |2017-02-27|2017-04-30 |
|4  |2017-04-23|2017-05-27 |
|5  |2017-04-29|2017-06-30 |
|6  |2017-06-13|2017-07-05 |
|7  |2017-06-13|2017-07-18 |
|8  |2017-06-16|2017-07-19 |
|9  |2017-07-09|2017-08-02 |
|10 |2017-07-18|2017-08-07 |
|11 |2017-07-28|2017-08-11 |
|12 |2017-07-28|2017-08-13 |
|13 |2017-08-04|2017-08-13 |
|14 |2017-08-13|2017-08-13 |
|15 |2017-08-13|2017-08-13 |
|16 |2017-08-13|2017-08-25 |
|17 |2017-08-13|2017-09-10 |
|18 |2017-08-31|2017-09-21 |
|19 |2017-10-03|2017-09-22 |
+---+----------+-----------+
```

I know there are many ways to do what I am asking using different pyspark APIs, however I would like to use the `Window` API to accomplish the following.

It is essentially a double for loop in any other situation.

For every date in `date_1`, look at every date in `date_2` that is in the same or subsequent rows, and count the number of occurrences where the difference falls within a week, month, ..., (the timeframe is irrelevant, but for consistency sake, let's go with week). Use these results to add another column with the count.

The challenge is getting the right `Window`(s) combination to consider both date columns.

Comment: Could you please provide example output of what you want to get? Your word description is kind of ambiguous. From what it now reads to me it sounds more like you just want one window over `date_1`.

Comment: Ok, I think I somehow read `subsequent rows` as `subsequent row` as singular instead of plural. So in terms of your question - do you need to order by `date_1` or by `id` regarding "subsequent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question's author correctly for each row X in the dataframe we want to go over all rows starting from that (ordered by e.g. `id`) and for each such row Y compare X.date_1 with Y.date_2. Number of rows Y for which difference between X.date_1 and Y.date_2 is less than e.g. 1 week should be added as a column to row X (e.g. X.result).

Unfortunately windowing functions are not providing a functionality to access `X.date_1` inside window functions and thus it is impossible to achieve using windowing functions.

This seems to be very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function) where author tries to do a similar thing for Postgres.

But then there is a way to actually do it though through a bit of cheating - i.e.  to "materialize" window frame for each Row in an array and then perform the needed operations. Not sure if in your view this would count, but that is the only way Window API could be used to resolve the problem. A possible solution could look like this (assuming we want to count number of rows Y going not earlier than X w.r.t `id` with `Y.date_2` between `X.date_1` and `X.date_1 + 7 days`):

```
import datetime
rawdata = [l.strip('|').replace('|', ' ').split() for l in '''|0  |2017-01-21|2017-04-01 |
|1  |2017-01-22|2017-04-24 |
|2  |2017-02-23|2017-04-30 |
|3  |2017-02-27|2017-04-30 |
|4  |2017-04-23|2017-05-27 |
|5  |2017-04-29|2017-06-30 |
|6  |2017-06-13|2017-07-05 |
|7  |2017-06-13|2017-07-18 |
|8  |2017-06-16|2017-07-19 |
|9  |2017-07-09|2017-08-02 |
|10 |2017-07-18|2017-08-07 |
|11 |2017-07-28|2017-08-11 |
|12 |2017-07-28|2017-08-13 |
|13 |2017-08-04|2017-08-13 |
|14 |2017-08-13|2017-08-13 |
|15 |2017-08-13|2017-08-13 |
|16 |2017-08-13|2017-08-25 |
|17 |2017-08-13|2017-09-10 |
|18 |2017-08-31|2017-09-21 |
|19 |2017-10-03|2017-09-22 |'''.split('\n')]
data = [(int(d[0]), datetime.date.fromisoformat(d[1]), datetime.date.fromisoformat(d[2])) for d in rawdata]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema='id: bigint, date_1: Date, date_2: Date')

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
window_spec = Window.orderBy('id').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
new_df = df.withColumn('materialized_frame_date_2', func.collect_list(df['date_2']).over(window_spec)) \
  .withColumn('result', func.expr('size(filter(materialized_frame_date_2, x -> datediff(x, date_1) BETWEEN 0 AND 7))')) \
  .drop('materialized_frame_date_2')
new_df.show()
```

The result:

```
+---+----------+----------+------+
| id|    date_1|    date_2|result|
+---+----------+----------+------+
|  0|2017-01-21|2017-04-01|     0|
|  1|2017-01-22|2017-04-24|     0|
|  2|2017-02-23|2017-04-30|     0|
|  3|2017-02-27|2017-04-30|     0|
|  4|2017-04-23|2017-05-27|     0|
|  5|2017-04-29|2017-06-30|     0|
|  6|2017-06-13|2017-07-05|     0|
|  7|2017-06-13|2017-07-18|     0|
|  8|2017-06-16|2017-07-19|     0|
|  9|2017-07-09|2017-08-02|     0|
| 10|2017-07-18|2017-08-07|     0|
| 11|2017-07-28|2017-08-11|     0|
| 12|2017-07-28|2017-08-13|     0|
| 13|2017-08-04|2017-08-13|     0|
| 14|2017-08-13|2017-08-13|     2|
| 15|2017-08-13|2017-08-13|     1|
| 16|2017-08-13|2017-08-25|     0|
| 17|2017-08-13|2017-09-10|     0|
| 18|2017-08-31|2017-09-21|     0|
| 19|2017-10-03|2017-09-22|     0|
+---+----------+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is helpful-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |id |date_1    |date_2
        |0  |2017-01-21|2017-04-01
        |1  |2017-01-22|2017-04-24
        |2  |2017-02-23|2017-04-30
        |3  |2017-02-27|2017-04-30
        |4  |2017-04-23|2017-05-27
        |5  |2017-04-29|2017-06-30
        |6  |2017-06-13|2017-07-05
        |7  |2017-06-13|2017-07-18
        |8  |2017-06-16|2017-07-19
        |9  |2017-07-09|2017-08-02
        |10 |2017-07-18|2017-08-07
        |11 |2017-07-28|2017-08-11
        |12 |2017-07-28|2017-08-13
        |13 |2017-08-04|2017-08-13
        |14 |2017-08-13|2017-08-13
        |15 |2017-08-13|2017-08-13
        |16 |2017-08-13|2017-08-25
        |17 |2017-08-13|2017-09-10
        |18 |2017-08-31|2017-09-21
        |19 |2017-10-03|2017-09-22
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |id |date_1             |date_2             |
      * +---+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |0  |2017-01-21 00:00:00|2017-04-01 00:00:00|
      * |1  |2017-01-22 00:00:00|2017-04-24 00:00:00|
      * |2  |2017-02-23 00:00:00|2017-04-30 00:00:00|
      * |3  |2017-02-27 00:00:00|2017-04-30 00:00:00|
      * |4  |2017-04-23 00:00:00|2017-05-27 00:00:00|
      * |5  |2017-04-29 00:00:00|2017-06-30 00:00:00|
      * |6  |2017-06-13 00:00:00|2017-07-05 00:00:00|
      * |7  |2017-06-13 00:00:00|2017-07-18 00:00:00|
      * |8  |2017-06-16 00:00:00|2017-07-19 00:00:00|
      * |9  |2017-07-09 00:00:00|2017-08-02 00:00:00|
      * |10 |2017-07-18 00:00:00|2017-08-07 00:00:00|
      * |11 |2017-07-28 00:00:00|2017-08-11 00:00:00|
      * |12 |2017-07-28 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|
      * |13 |2017-08-04 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|
      * |14 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|
      * |15 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|
      * |16 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-08-25 00:00:00|
      * |17 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-09-10 00:00:00|
      * |18 |2017-08-31 00:00:00|2017-09-21 00:00:00|
      * |19 |2017-10-03 00:00:00|2017-09-22 00:00:00|
      * +---+-------------------+-------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- date_1: timestamp (nullable = true)
      * |-- date_2: timestamp (nullable = true)
      */
```

### count the number of occurrences where the difference(date_1-date_2) falls within a week

```scala
    // week
    val weekDiff = 7
    val w = Window.orderBy("id", "date_1", "date_2")
      .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    df.withColumn("count", sum(
      when(datediff($"date_1", $"date_2") <= weekDiff, 1).otherwise(0)
    ).over(w))
      .orderBy("id")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
      * |id |date_1             |date_2             |count|
      * +---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
      * |0  |2017-01-21 00:00:00|2017-04-01 00:00:00|19   |
      * |1  |2017-01-22 00:00:00|2017-04-24 00:00:00|18   |
      * |2  |2017-02-23 00:00:00|2017-04-30 00:00:00|17   |
      * |3  |2017-02-27 00:00:00|2017-04-30 00:00:00|16   |
      * |4  |2017-04-23 00:00:00|2017-05-27 00:00:00|15   |
      * |5  |2017-04-29 00:00:00|2017-06-30 00:00:00|14   |
      * |6  |2017-06-13 00:00:00|2017-07-05 00:00:00|13   |
      * |7  |2017-06-13 00:00:00|2017-07-18 00:00:00|12   |
      * |8  |2017-06-16 00:00:00|2017-07-19 00:00:00|11   |
      * |9  |2017-07-09 00:00:00|2017-08-02 00:00:00|10   |
      * |10 |2017-07-18 00:00:00|2017-08-07 00:00:00|9    |
      * |11 |2017-07-28 00:00:00|2017-08-11 00:00:00|8    |
      * |12 |2017-07-28 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|7    |
      * |13 |2017-08-04 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|6    |
      * |14 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|5    |
      * |15 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-08-13 00:00:00|4    |
      * |16 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-08-25 00:00:00|3    |
      * |17 |2017-08-13 00:00:00|2017-09-10 00:00:00|2    |
      * |18 |2017-08-31 00:00:00|2017-09-21 00:00:00|1    |
      * |19 |2017-10-03 00:00:00|2017-09-22 00:00:00|0    |
      * +---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
      */
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be what the author asked though - they said they wanted to count rows after a given row for which date_2 is within a date of date_1 of original row (i.e. in the window frame for a row X each row Y should have Y.date_2 compared to the date_1 of original row X, not to date_1 of the same row date_2 is coming from).

Comment: I'll wait for the author's confirmation. This is my understanding till now from the description. Anyways  i'm ready to change this initial solution to more concrete one based on the feedback from author

Comment: Fair enough. It's just that with such reading I don't understand meaning of the part "The challenge is getting the right Window(s) combination to consider both date columns".

Comment: @SomeshwarKale, Alexander is correct. The question asks to find the count, for each row, where `date_2` (in the same row or after) falls within one week of `date_1`. Take a look at your answer. For example, with the first row there are not **19** dates in `date_2` that fall within one week of `2017-01-21`. Basically you did a `count` on an `unboundedFollowing` `Window`. Also #PySpark.

Comment: @CaptainKirk, I believe, only few had tried to solve this problem due to the ambiguity/difference in understanding in the problem. I think, its author's responsibility to eradicate that by providing expected output. This will indeed help author to get quality answers and turnaround time can be shortened. Can you please spend some time on the question to provide expected out put?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale NO