# Windows Function Filter Clause in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have following table in a Redshift. I am trying to implement a filter clause in windows function that is described over here - [Referencing current row in FILTER clause of window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function) but filter clause does not work in Redshift

Trying to run following query in Redshift:

```
select date, super_location , super_location, location, condition, 
,count(location) FILTER (where condition = 1) 
 over (partition by super_location,super_location order by date) as count
from table1
```

Sample Data:

```
date       | super_location | sub_super_location| location| condition
-----------|---------------|-------------------| -------- | ----------
2022-06-28 | AAA           | AA                | A1       | 1

2022-06-27 | AAA           | AA                | A1       | 0

2022-06-26 | AAA           | AA                | A1       | 0

2022-06-28 | AAA           | AA                | A2       | 1

2022-06-27 | AAA           | AA                | A2       | 1
```

I want to count locations where condition = 1 and partition by super location, sub super location and order_date. The count should be visible in every row. So the resulting dataset should look like this -

Resulting Dataset:

```
Order_date | super_location | sub_super_location | location | condition |count
-----------|----------------|------------------- | -------- | ----------|-----
2022-06-28 | AAA1           | AA1                | A1       | 1         |2 (counting A1 and A2 on 06/28 where condition = 1)

2022-06-27 | AAA1           | AA1                | A1       | 0         |1 (counting A2 on 06/27 where where condition = 1)

2022-06-26 | AAA1           | AA1                | A1       | 0         |0 (no location with condition = 1 on 06/26)

2022-06-28 | AAA1           | AA1                | A2       | 1         |2 (counting A1 and A2 on 06/28 where condition = 1)

2022-06-27 | AAA1           | AA1                | A1       | 1         |1 (counting A1 on 06/27 where condition = 1)
```

Comment: are you sure that redshift has that feature?

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(WhatYouAlreadyHadInTheOver)`

Comment: Clever. You should add that as an answer @HoneyBadger.